# SSRS report with new shared dataset Deployment

Tags: reporting-services

I have modified a report which has already been deployed by adding a new shared data set.

I would like to know how to deploy these changes to the report server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the report from the server using Report Manager
2. Deploy the new shared dataset.
3. Deploy the report.

Comment: thanks for reply.currently i don't have rights to remove report from server. can i redeploy the report with out removing the report from server? or can i deploy all project items(datasets, rdl files) to report server?

Comment: You can try to redeploy the report, without deleting the existing report. Normally it will work, but depending on whether you've made changes to parameters and other stuff, you might need to tweak some settings on the report inside Report Manager after deployment.

Comment: do i need to deploy complete project or only these two files(rsd and rdl) are enough to get the report in server?

Comment: It's enough to deploy only the rsd and rdl files.